# ssh using @ without a username

Tags: ssh, ovirt, ssh-config

Im doing some setup via the following guide,

https://www.ovirt.org/develop/dev-process/working-with-gerrit.html

Theres a step to verify the ssh config but it involves doing

```
ssh @gerrit.ovirt.org
```

This looks like a typo, don't we need a user for the @ part. If no user, no @  is my understanding?

```
[root@dub-svrfarm27 ~]# ssh @gerrit.ovirt.org
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
          [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
          [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
          [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
          [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
          [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
          [user@]hostname [command]
```

This being said...the final bit of my id_rsa.pub has this

```
71MgP8w== root@
```

So maybe there is method to this, im not sure.

Comment: You should be correct.... ssh shouldn't work like that....

Comment: The final part of the public key file is a comment, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo. Look again at the usage message:

```
[user@]hostname
```

The `@` is legal if, and only if, a user name is supplied in addition to the required host name.

Comment: Thanks yeah i removed the @ and was able to continue. Much appreciated